# How to receive and process location changes when an Activity is paused

Tags: android, service, android-service, android-location, android-intentservice

I am looking for a bit of app design advice.

I have an app that connects to the Google Location Services and tracks location coordinates it receives. These are displayed as a path on the UI.

When the screen times out and goes blank then this `Activity` will, of course, shut down as per the normal Activity life cycle.

However - I atill want to record the co-ordinates coming back in each  `onLocationChanged` event from Location Services, but, of course, the `Activity` has paused so it cannot do that.

I don't particularly want to prevent the screen from blanking in the Manifest (and thus the `Activity` would never pause). Though I believe it would still pause if, say, a phone call is received etc.

**My** solution would be to start an `IntentService` in one of the `Activity` pausing events (either `onPause`, `onStop` or `onSaveInstanceState`) to receive Location updates, and then when the `Activity` restarts, collect the data from the Service and close the Service down.

Would this be an efficient and correct way of achieving this, or is there some Android black art that I don't know about? If so, is `IntentService` the correct way to go about it (or should I use `Service`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to tie up loose ends, I'll add my own answer to this now I have implemented something.

My solution in the end was **not** an `IntentService`. This was because I thought that the `IntentService` would consider its work to be the actual setting up of the `LocationService` and once that work had been completed then it would shut itself down rather than hang about waiting for `LocationService` 'pings'.

Therefore, I implemented a normal `Service`, but I bound it to the calling `Activity`. I also set up a callback to the `Activity`. This way when a 'ping' was received I could process it and pass back the data directly to the `Activity`. Also, the `Service` would remain alive as long as the binding was in place. I clear the binder when the `Activity` is destroyed.

This worked perfectly....HOWEVER

I then discovered that the reason that the `LocationService` 'pings' were not being handled in the `Activity` was bacause I was disconnecting the `GoogleAPIClient` when the `Activity` `onStop` was called. Having removed this, the `Activity` processed the 'pings'even in its stopped state, so no `Service` was required anyway.

Therefore the correct answer to this question is... `Activity` should continue processing in the background (unless it's destroyed for memory management purposes), so check you're not stopping stuff in your 'shutdown' handlers `onPause` `onStop` etc. Then you won't waste time writing services like I did!

Answer (score 0):

Proberly a normal service that gets restarted by an alarmmanager is an better idea.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why this is better? Wouldn't this just be a `service` that is started by a scheduler rather than when it's actually needed (i.e. when my app pauses)?